# how I can change the Stack title in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I have a header.js file in my shared folder. I want it to use it on every stack to design the Header and Information. In my App.js I load the header like this:

```
App.js
...
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{
      headerTitle: () => <Header /> (<-- Here the Header.js file )
    }} initialRouteName="AppTabs">
      <Stack.Screen name="AppTabs" component={AppTabs} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
```

Header.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Entypo } from '@expo/vector-icons'; 

const Header = ({ navigation }) => {
  console.log(navigation);
  return (
    <View style={styles.header}>
      <Entypo name="menu" size={24} color="black" />
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.headerText}>TITEL TO CHANGE BUT HOW?</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
};
```

How Can I change the title automaticly like this:

```
<Text>{title}</Text>
```

Comment: Typically you'd pass this as a prop to your Header component. Or you'll have to wire it up elsewhere depending on where the value for your `{title}` bit is coming from.

Comment: But without more details about where the value of the title is coming from it's difficult to answer your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Header.js` should look like this.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Entypo } from '@expo/vector-icons';

const Header = ({ children }) => {
  console.log(children);
  return (
    <View style={styles.header}>
      <Entypo name="menu" size={24} color="black" />
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.headerText}>{children}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Your `Stack.Navigator` should look like this -

```
<Stack.Navigator
  screenOptions={{
    headerTitle: (props) => <Header {...props} />, // this prop contains screen name
  }}
  initialRouteName="AppTabs">
  <Stack.Screen name="AppTabs" component={AppTabs} />
</Stack.Navigator>;
```